# Set Windows 8.1 Alarms app to ring forever till the user stop it

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-store-app, alarm, alarm-clock

When I set an alarm to ring at specific time on the Windows 8.1 Alarms application, it rings only 5 mins then stop ringing.

How could I set it to ring forever till I only stop it (Wake up)?

Comment: Use a different application.

Comment: I'll bet there is a registry tweak for this windows 8 pre-installed app, but I couldn't locate it

Comment: @Ramhound Could you please recommend any app similar to Windows' application? I love this good looking Windows app, and I won't install any other app if it really deserves taking my computer resources and have similar capabilities to the Windows' app.

Answer (score 0):

Work-around would be to set multiple alarms, one every five minutes, until you get up and turn your computer off...

Comment: I already do this solution, but it's very annoying and requires a lot of effort!